# Is it possible to re-point operational layers ArcGIS Mobile projects v.3.0

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-mobile

We have an ArcGIS mobile project with two operational layers for data collection. The layers source from a GIS server on the cloud, running on top of an SDE. The database has a feature dataset, and the editable feature classes within. The editable feature classes have a lot of fields, and the mobile project has all the layers' and their fields' settings.

We want to deploy projects for a number of different regions, thus've we built a separate feature dataset and its child feature classes for each region, and published the GIS services for the mobile devices to interact with. We want to replicate the mobile project and have one project for each region.

Question: is it possible to make a copy of a mobile project and re-point the operational layers to a different service and still keep the settings (fields are the same as all feature classes have the same schema), to avoid having to configure the layers by manually doing all the ticks again? Or, is there a way to have the settings in a text file to read from? We're using Mobile Project Center 3.0.

Thanks